# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null deleteRows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code to delete multiple specific row in a table

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('comp');
  var r = s.getRange('A:A');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='is a unique address')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

The sheet name is correct, the column is populated and the text bit is also correct.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
deleteRows  @ Code.gs:4
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a is a duplicate address, seen 13 times |  |
| b is a duplicate address, seen 14 times |  |
| c is a duplicate address, seen 7 times |  |
| d is a duplicate address, seen 3 times |  |
| e is a unique address |  |
| f is a duplicate address, seen 2 times |  |
| g is a duplicate address, seen 11 times |  |
| h is a duplicate address, seen 2 times |  |
| i is a duplicate address, seen 4 times |  |
| j is a unique address |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if there are no trailing spaces in the tab name ?

Also, a bit further in the code (and assuming the 'unique adress' is in column A) so may have to change this line

```
if(v[0,i]=='is a unique address')
```

to

```
if(v[i][0].indexOf('is a unique address')>-1)
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned that. 
but `if(v[i][0]=='is a unique address')`als doesn't work

Comment: Tested your code and it works fine. is 'is an unique address' a placeholder for an address you want to match ? Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Or better yet, share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Added the table (shorten version) (a,b,c.. equals sensitive information)

Comment: Ok. You're not looking for an exact match. Try using indexOf. See my updated answer.